# Java Array Destroy

Tags: java, arrays, null

If I use "Array_Name[] = NULL", does the garbage collector of java collect the rest of the array?

Comment: Minor point: by `Array_Name[] = NULL` you mean `Array_Name = null`, right?

Comment: Really should be `arrayName = null` ... style is important too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only if `Array_Name` had actually been referencing an array to begin with. And only if there are no other references to the array. And it will reclaim only those elements of the array which aren't referenced by anything outside of the array. And it will only do so when it feels like getting around to it :-)

(The syntax `Array_Name[] = NULL` isn't really meaningful. But I'm assuming you'd done something like:

```
 Foo[] Array_Name = new Foo[n];
 //...
 Array_Name = null; // Note the lowercase "null"
```

This *might* make the array a proper target for garbage collection, given the conditions I described above.)

Comment: +1 *...it will only do so when it feels like getting around to it...* (That is, the GC is largely non-deterministic -- from the point of Java code -- when it runs.)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with everything Dan mentioned above but you can actually trigger garbage collection manually by calling System.gc(). Of course as mentioned this will only collect objects that are no longer referenced by anything else.

Comment: You might want to mention that calling System.gc() is highly discouraged.

Comment: I agree, I'm just presenting the option.